# Direct IP to IP call

Tags: web-services, ip, chat, voip

I could set up my own PC as a host (using Xitami application and opening port 80), so that people could type in (http://my-ip-address) and they would log into my site (on my pc). What I would like to know is there a possibility to set up a direct IP to IP connection of some sort to make a voice call (VoIP)? I don't want Skype at all because I have to log into their server but I already have my own server I don't need them and I don't need their application, I want to find out if it's possible to set up my own. Any suggestions?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I run both Linux and Windows (dual boot), so a solution that covers either one is good?

Comment: I have finally found a way to have a PC to PC direct connection through the internet (and hence a real IP to IP voice chat) without using extra services (like skype, msn or others). It's a pity that because of ignorance and bigotry they have closed this post, otherwise this valuable information could have been openly shared with the community.

Comment: how did you manage to make voice call between two ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard http://www.asterisk.org is quite good. There is also http://www.freeswitch.org/ and http://www.elastix.org/